# Flat List not updated on state change

Tags: react-native

I am creating dinner decider app and want to add items into an array from the user input. input added to an array list and shows in alert box but not reloat the FlatList. Please help
Here is my code for the same.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {items:[{key:'Pasta'},{key:'Pizza'}],userdata:''}
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header></Header>
        <Content style={{padding:20}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize: 30, textAlign:'center', marginVertical:30,}}>Food Decider</Text>
          <Item floatingLabel>
            <Label>Add Item</Label>
            <Input 
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({userdata:text})}
            />
          </Item>
          <Button block success style={{marginTop: 20,}}
             onPress={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}
          >
            <Text>Add Item</Text>
          </Button>
          <FlatList 
            data = {this.state.items}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
          />
        </Content>
      </Container>      
    );
  }
  onSubmit(){
    this.state.items.push({key:this.state.userdata});
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.items));
  }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use prop legacyImplementation=true in FlatList so that it does the real time changes to the FlatList.

Use:

```
<FlatList legacyImplementation=true />
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all in you onSubmit function you didn't set the state just push a value

```
onSubmit(){
this.state.items.push({key:this.state.userdata});
alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.items));
```

}

whereas it should be something like this

```
 onSubmit(){
let newState = this.state.items;
newState.push({key:this.state.userdata});
this.setState({items:newState});
alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.items));
```

}

and also bind your onSubmit function  in the constructor like  this

```
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {items:[{key:'Pasta'},{key:'Pizza'}],userdata:''}
this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
```

}

Comment: Thanks Anwar Gul for your reply, I have made changes in my code accordingly but still not be able to reload my FlatList after changing values in array.

Answer (score 0):

In Flat list there is also one more option

```
"extraData={this.state.metaData}"
```

you can use this to reset/reload the FlatList on your action complete ,you can use like this:

```
constructor(props){
     super(props);
    this.state={
    metaData:false,
    }
}
<FlatList 
         data = {this.state.items}
         renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
         extraData={this.state.metaData}
          />
```

after button click you can use this

```
onSubmit(){
   let {metaTAbBarData}=this.state
    this.state.items.push({key:this.state.userdata});
    this.setState({metaData:!metaData})
  }
```

it will reload when you click on submit button
it will help you , its help me

Comment: hey @MayankGarg can you check this Q please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780167/i-cant-re-render-the-flatlist-after-empty-data

Answer (score 0):

```
onSubmit(){    
 /*
  *  FlatList is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render              
  *  if props remain shallow-equal So, We are Cloning the items array to           
  *  clonedArray, So that the reference to this.state.items  will change.
  *  Means this.state.items === clonedArray will give false value.
  */
   let clonedArray = this.state.items.slice();
   clonedArray.push({key:this.state.userdata});
   this.setState({items: clonedArray});
}
```