# I can't re-render the FlatList after empty data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I Get the data from firebase real-time and put it I FlatList and when I delete if from Console "Firebase" it's deleted from the List in screen very well but the last item in the Array "Data" couldn't be deleted I don't know why!

I use an onRefresh Props but not help me because we all know the DB is real-time and when we will add any item it's will be in the last without refresh it So it's not work with the last item too and just the loading stuck without re-render the FlatList

**Although I use .once('value') when I get data from DB, refresh work but when I refresh after deleting the last item the loading refresh stuck and can't disappear the last item**

so how can I solve this issue?

here is my code

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Dimensions,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

const {width} = Dimensions.get('window');
export default class PendingOrders extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      orders: [],
      forceUpdate: true,
      isFetching: false,
    };
  }
  onRefresh = () => {
    this.setState({isFetching: true}, () => this.getApiData());
  };
  getApiData = () => {
    try {
      const uid = auth().currentUser.uid;
      const Orders = database().ref(`usersOrders/${uid}`);
      Orders.on('value', snapshot => {
        let orders = [];
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          if (childSnapshot.val().status == 'pending') {
            orders.push({
              buildingNumber: childSnapshot.val().buildingNumber,
              service: childSnapshot.val().categoryName,
              date: childSnapshot.val().date,
              time: childSnapshot.val().time,
              description: childSnapshot.val().problemDescription,
              status: childSnapshot.val().status,
              images: childSnapshot.val().Images,
            });
            this.setState({orders, forceUpdate: false, isFetching: false}, () =>
              console.log(this.state.orders),
            );
            return;
          }
        });
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error fetching data: ', err);
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getApiData();
  }

  _listEmptyComponent = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Image
          style={{
            width,
            height: width * 0.7,
            resizeMode: 'contain',
          }}
          source={require('../../assets/empty.png')}
        />
        <Text
          style={{
            color: '#000',
            marginVertical: 15,
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 20,
          }}>
       No item found
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };
  render() {
    console.log('is?', this.state.forceUpdate);
    return (
      <FlatList
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={this.state.orders}
        extraData={this.state.isFetching}
        onRefresh={() => this.onRefresh()}
        ListEmptyComponent={this._listEmptyComponent()}
        refreshing={this.state.isFetching}
        contentContainerStyle={{
          flexBasis: '100%',
        }}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() =>
                this.props.navigation.navigate('OrderDetailsScreen', {
                  service: item.service,
                  time: item.time,
                  date: item.date,
                  description: item.description,
                  images: item.images,
                  status: item.status,
                })
              }
              style={{
                margin: 15,
                borderRadius: 10,
                borderWidth: 1,
                flexDirection: 'row',
                borderColor: '#ddd',
              }}>
              <Image
                style={{
                  borderRadius: 10,
                  borderTopLeftRadius: 0,
                  borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
                  width: 150,
                  height: 150,
                }}
                resizeMode="cover"
                source={item.images[0]}
              />
              <View
                style={{
                  margin: 5,
                  marginLeft: 10,
                  justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
                }}>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    marginBottom: 5,
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: 16,
                    marginTop: 5,
                  }}>
                  {item.service}
                </Text>
                <View
                  style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'space-around',
                  }}>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      // paddingHorizontal: 5,
                    }}>
                    <Icon name="date-range" color="#AEACAC" size={20} />
                    <Text style={{paddingHorizontal: 5}}>{item.date}</Text>
                  </View>
                  <View
                    style={{
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                      alignItems: 'center',
                      paddingHorizontal: 5,
                    }}>
                    <Icon name="access-time" color="#AEACAC" size={20} />
                    <Text style={{paddingHorizontal: 5}}>{item.time}</Text>
                  </View>
                </View>
                <Text
                  numberOfLines={1}
                  ellipsizeMode="tail"
                  style={{marginBottom: 5, width: 160, marginTop: 5}}>
                  {item.description}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: ``this.setState({isFetching: true}, () => this.getApiData());`` looks like the problem here. Why are you calling ``getApiData`` inside ``setState``?

Comment: @romin21 it's a callback to get the newData after I refresh!, and the issue relates with Flatlist cuz when I don't use pull to refresh and just FlatList I can see the same issue with the last item, I think should empty the Data manually

Comment: What `console.log(this.state.orders)` printed out after you delete the last orders?

Comment: @Izzuddiin it's not log anything "Logger is empty"

Comment: so, what is `childSnapshot.val().status` value after you delete the last orders?

Comment: the issue solved after setState order outside ```snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {...})``` :) have an explanation for it ?

Comment: Therefore I asked to you, what was `childSnapshot.val().status` value. Because, according to above code, you only update `order` state when `childSnapshot.val().status` is `pending` **AND** inside `childSnapshot` loop. I guess, `snapshot` is returned empty array when you delete the last orders. So, it will not go into your loop, and of course never update your `order` state

Answer (score 1):

The key for re activating flatlist is `extraData`. just change it's value to something else and it will trigger flatlist re rendering. for simplicity pass a boolean value to extraData. every time you want to re active the flatlist, just toggle the value of `extraData`

Comment: can you check if refetchFunction is called after changing extraData

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64099988/react-native-how-to-update-flatlist-of-posts-new-likes) i tell him to use `extraData` as u say but it's faced the same issue :\

Comment: maybe there is a bug in your code. keep trace it properly with console.log and you can find the solution. check if extraData value is changing. check if reFetch function is called