# React Native - how to update FlatList of posts (new likes, ...)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, infinite-scroll

### Introduction

I am developing a list of posts, which is nested in a flatlist that has a pull to refresh implemented, and each post (rendered in a Card) has the avatar of the user who uploaded it. Also, it is possible for a user to change its avatar, so I need to update the posts FlatList  with the new user avatar.

I have read something about the ExtraData prop but doesn't work in my case.

### Code

```
// Posts Screen
export default function Posts(props) {
   const {
      userData: {
         username,
         avatar
      }
   } = props;

   const [data, setData] = useState([]); // [{ avatar, username, photoUri, likes }, ...]

   let previousAvatar = useRef(avatar).current;

   // ... Fetch the data
 
   // This is the wrong(?) stuff I am doing to update the FlatList
    useEffect(() => {
     if (previousAvatar !== avatar) {
       // For each post, change the avatar
       setPosts(
         posts.map((post) => ({
           ...post,
           avatar: avatar,
         }))
       );

       // Save the new avatar
       previousAvatar = avatar;
     }
   }, [ownerData]);


   return (<FlatList data={data} renderIt... />)
   
}
```

### What I am doing

When I detect that the user has change its avatar, I modify the data which is passed to the FlatList, changing the avatar uri. I think this is bad, as there can be 100K posts in the list...

Also, I need to update the flatlist when new likes, new username, ... So I think this is not viable

### What I have tried

```
// Posts Screen
export default function Posts(props) {
   const {
      userData
   } = props;

   ...
    
   return <FlatList data={data} extraData={userData} ... />

}
```

In the documentation says "By passing extraData to FlatList we make sure FlatList itself will re-render when the state changes.", but for me, this doesn't work, as userData is received via props.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You could use pull to refresh - so if you pull down the flatlist would rerender with the new elements. But I dont know if this would suite your needs, but you can let me know.

Comment: @yeslamFaded ". I think this is bad, as there can be 100K posts in the list"

Comment: yeah thats why I didnt just post is as an answer - it could take to long to load even though I dont know if elements that did not get changed rerender fully.

Comment: 100K items is a problem if you load them all at once, even if the Flatlist only renders what is on the visible area of the screen. You should introduce a pagination feature calling only a set number of items everytime and only pass a subset of your items to the flatlist data. Then all you need to do is update the data everytime and you are good to go.

Comment: Yeah I am doing this with pagination, but at the time the user scrolls down, more posts are added to my data array. Regardless of whether my flatlist ignores those posts that are not in the viewport, the data array will be as longer as the user scroll position, so if I do like I am doing, I will have to map 100k items (if the users' scroll position is at the end of the list)....

Comment: Try to add a boolean trigger and pass it to extraData and when you update posts update the trigger and check if it solves the issue or not

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    setRefresh(!refresh);
  }, [posts]);

  return (
    <FlatList
       data={posts}
       extraData={refresh}    - Tried this but didn't work

Comment: Can u share ur code on snack?

Comment: Okey, I will build it and paste the link here. Might take a little time.

Answer (score 1):

flatList will render the data and not the extraData. try setting the extraData to a boolean and reverse the boolean value everytime you need to update the list.

Comment: will extraData throw a re-render if the fiven value has changed?

Comment: I think it is hard for js to know that values of some keys in an object has changed thus by changing the data passed to the data props and then toggle the extraData boolean you will cause a re-render.